# Hawkular resolving "Missing" triggers

Tags: hawkular

I am new to Hawkular and I have created a trigger for alert when a device did not communicate with me for a given time period (10s for testing).

```
        "trigger": {
            "id": "YYY,
            "name": "My trigger",
            "description": "",
            "type": "GROUP",
            "firingMatch": "ANY",
            "autoResolve": true,
            "autoResolveAlerts": true,
            "enabled": true
        },
        "conditions": [{
            "triggerMode": "FIRING",
            "type": "MISSING",
            "dataId": "XXX",
            "interval": 10000
        }]
```

Now I want to resolve any such alerts when the device start communicating.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed with [comment](http://www.hawkular.org/blog/2015/08/25/hawkular-alerts-autoresolve.html) by Lucas Ponce

```
"trigger": {
    "id": "YYY",
    "name": "My trigger",
    "description": "",
    "type": "GROUP",
    "firingMatch": "ANY",
    "autoResolve": true,
    "autoResolveAlerts": true,
    "enabled": true
},
"conditions": [{
        "triggerMode": "FIRING",
        "type": "MISSING",
        "dataId": "XXX",
        "interval": 10000
    },
    {
        "triggerMode": "AUTORESOLVE",
        "type": "AVAILABILITY",
        "dataId": "Collar_UIDHEX",
        "operator": "UP"
    }
]
```